# Creating a Random Feature Array in Spark DataFrames

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, vector

When creating an `ALS` model, we can extract a `userFactors` DataFrame and an `itemFactors` DataFrame. These DataFrames contain a column with an Array.

I would like to generate some random data and union it to the `userFactors` DataFrame.

Here is my code:

```
 val df1: DataFrame  = Seq((123, 456, 4.0), (123, 789, 5.0), (234, 456, 4.5), (234, 789, 1.0)).toDF("user", "item", "rating")
val model1 = (new ALS()
 .setImplicitPrefs(true)
 .fit(df1))

val iF = model1.itemFactors
val uF = model1.userFactors
```

I then create a random DataFrame using a `VectorAssembler` with this function:

```
def makeNew(df: DataFrame, rank: Int): DataFrame = {
    var df_dummy = df
    var i: Int = 0
    var inputCols: Array[String] = Array()
    for (i <- 0 to rank) {
       df_dummy = df_dummy.withColumn("feature".concat(i.toString), rand())
       inputCols = inputCols :+ "feature".concat(i.toString)
      }
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(inputCols)
      .setOutputCol("userFeatures")
    val output = assembler.transform(df_dummy)
    output.select("user", "userFeatures")
  }
```

I then create the DataFrame with new user IDs and add the random vectors and bias:

```
val usersDf: DataFrame = Seq(567), (678)).toDF("user")
var usersFactorsNew: DataFrame = makeNew(usersDf, 20)
```

The problem arises when I union the two DataFrames.

`usersFactorsNew.union(uF)` produces the error:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> <> array<float> at the second column of the second table;;
```

If I print the schema, the `uF` DataFrame has a feature vector of type `Array[Float]` and the `usersFactorsNew` DataFrame as a feature vector of type `Vector`.

My question is how to change the type of the `Vector` to an Array in order to perform the union.

I tried writing this `udf` with little success:

```
val toArr: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector => Array[Double] = _.toArray
val toArrUdf = udf(toArr)
```

Perhaps the `VectorAssembler` is not the best option for this task. However, at the moment, it is the only option I have found. I would love to get some recommendations for something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a dummy dataframe and using `VectorAssembler` to generate a random feature vector, you can simply use an `UDF` directly. The `userFactors` from the `ALS` model will return an `Array[Float]` so the output from the `UDF` should match that.

```
val createRandomArray = udf((rank: Int) => {
  Array.fill(rank)(Random.nextFloat)
})
```

Note that this will give numbers in the interval [0.0, 1.0] (same as the `rand()` used in the question), if other numbers are required, modify as fit.

Using a rank of 3 and the `userDf`:

```
val usersFactorsNew = usersDf.withColumn("userFeatures", createRandomArray(lit(3)))
```

will give a dataframe as follows (of course with random feature values)

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
|user|userFeatures                                              |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
|567 |[0.6866711267486822,0.7257031656127676,0.983562255688249] |
|678 |[0.7013908820314967,0.41029552817665327,0.554591149586789]|
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Joining this dataframe with the `uF` dataframe should now be possible.

---

The reason the `UDF` did not work should be due to it being an `Array[Double] while you need an`Array[Float]`for the`union`. It should be possible to fix with a`map(_.toFloat)`.

```
val toArr: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector => Array[Float] = _.toArray.map(_.toFloat)
val toArrUdf = udf(toArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your process are all correct. Even the `udf` function is working successfully. All you need to do is change the last part of `makeNew` function as

```
def makeNew(df: DataFrame, rank: Int): DataFrame = {
  var df_dummy = df
  var i: Int = 0
  var inputCols: Array[String] = Array()
  for (i <- 0 to rank) {
    df_dummy = df_dummy.withColumn("feature".concat(i.toString), rand())
    inputCols = inputCols :+ "feature".concat(i.toString)
  }
  val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(inputCols)
    .setOutputCol("userFeatures")
  val output = assembler.transform(df_dummy)
  output.select(col("id"), toArrUdf(col("userFeatures")).as("features"))
}
```

and you should be perfect to go so that when you do (I **created userDf with id column** and **not user column**)

```
val usersDf: DataFrame = Seq((567), (678)).toDF("id")
var usersFactorsNew: DataFrame = makeNew(usersDf, 20)
usersFactorsNew.union(uF).show(false)
```

you should be getting

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|567|[0.8259185719733708, 0.327713892339658, 0.049547223031371046, 0.056661808506210054, 0.5846626163454274, 0.038497936270104005, 0.8970865088803417, 0.8840660648882804, 0.837866669938156, 0.9395263094918058, 0.09179528484355126, 0.4915430644129799, 0.11083447052043116, 0.5122858182953718, 0.4302683812966408, 0.3862741815833828, 0.6189322403095068, 0.3000371006293433, 0.09331299668168902, 0.7421838728601371, 0.855867963988993]|
|678|[0.7686514248005568, 0.5473580740023187, 0.072945344124282, 0.36648594574355287, 0.9780202082328863, 0.5289221651923784, 0.3719451099963028, 0.2824660794505932, 0.4873197501260199, 0.9364676464120849, 0.011539929543513794, 0.5240615794930654, 0.6282546154521298, 0.995256022569878, 0.6659179561266975, 0.8990775317754092, 0.08650071017556926, 0.5190186149992805, 0.056345335742325475, 0.6465357505620791, 0.17913532817943245] |
|123|[0.04177388548851013, 0.26762014627456665, -0.19617630541324615, 0.34298020601272583, 0.19632814824581146, -0.2748605012893677, 0.07724890112876892, 0.4277132749557495, 0.1927199512720108, -0.40271613001823425]                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|234|[0.04139673709869385, 0.26520395278930664, -0.19440513849258423, 0.3398836553096771, 0.1945556253194809, -0.27237895131111145, 0.07655145972967148, 0.42385169863700867, 0.19098000228405, -0.39908021688461304]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```